# Homography rectangle looks distorted, as if the camera has a birds eye view

Tags: opencv, 3d, camera, homography

But the Markers are all correct, so I am wondering what kind of settings I could adjust to get the rectangle fit nicely around the image in the webcam view. I am using openCVsharp.

Comment: When you say "the markers are all correct" what exactly does that mean?  A homography is a matrix that maps between sets of 2D points.  If you multiply your points in image 1 by your homography do you get the coordinates of your points in image 2?  If so your homography is working perfectly.

Comment: Hi, sorry, what I mean is, the detected markers in image 1 do match points in image 2. Imagine image 1 a flat normal image as reference, image 2 comes from a webcam! So, if the markers wouldnt match, then the disorted rectangle makes sense, but in my case not. It is al augmented reality stuff, I did the detection with SURF. Those are markers. But the openCV is quit advance, so I am not sure what to do with the matrix parameters. For instance, one can set parameters like FC64c2 and something like that. So summ up, I need actually 4 corner points that do fit nice on the image in the webcam.

Comment: I have not used openCVsharp but I would recommend testing your homography finder on data that you generate.  Make 4 points of a rectangle, then transform each of them by a 3x3 matrix, feed your two sets of 4 points into the algorithm and make sure that it gives you back your 3x3 matrix.  If it does, then make sure you don't have a coordinate system problem.

Comment: It would be helpful if you clarified the question more.  When you say it appears as though the camera has a birds eye view, why is that bad?  What should it look like?  Are you trying to transform a rectangle into a distorted rectangle or a distorted rectangle into a regular rectangle?

Comment: yes, i agree, kinda hard to explain, so I made an image. Please see this screenshot: http://www.mvfusion.nl/rectangle_question.jpg
The white rectangle is distorted, it should look like the green, because that one does fit the image on the right side. The green rectangle is the one I just drawed to showcase, the white one comes from openCVsharp.  
This is the small code part that somehow generates the homegraphy, but I have no idea what it does. ;-)
if (Cv.FindHomography(_pt1, _pt2, homography, HomographyMethod.Ransac, 5) == 0)

Comment: You need to post more information.  How did you generate the white rectangle from the homography?  Where did you get _pt1 and _pt2?

Comment: Heey, I posted the source here:
http://www.mvfusion.nl/src_surf.txt
I appreciate that you take the time to look at this! 
The function 'translateCorners' is the one that creates this rectangle. OnDrawGizmos is just the drawing part. 
The code is based upon the source that can be found here:
http://www.chrisevansdev.com/computer-vision-opensurf.html

Comment: I am sorry but I am not going to take the time to debug your code for you if you don't narrow the problem down more.  Test the homography finding function like I suggested above.  You will in all likelihood discover that it works.  If it does work, then the problem is in the points you are passing to it.  Verify that they are in fact correct.  Your problem needs to be more specific

Comment: No problem, I thougth I was very specific with the drawing but I was just hoping someone could look at this and say, "oh you need to add this or that"

Comment: I got it working! Long story short, I just had to switch some parameters. I was feeding the points from img 2 to array nr 1 and vice verca and it suppose to be points img2 => array 2. The rectangle does fit perfect around the image now!